# 1画面の機能を別ファイルにしたい

Tags: android

Androidについて質問があります。

1画面にGridViewとListViewを 1対1の比で上下に配置するレイアウトを持つアプリを考えています。

上のGridViewでタップしたら, そのイベントでListViewを更新というように連携させたいのですが, activityファイルが肥大化していくのが少し気になっています。

これらのViewの管理はそれぞれ別activityに落とし込みたいのですが, それは可能なんでしょうか?

またそうした場合, タップイベントの取得がどういう流れになるのかも知りたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Fragmentを使えばよいと思います。
最善のやり方かは分かりませんが少しコードも書いておきます。

MainActivity.java

```
//importは省略します。
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText etext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //レイアウトにFrameLayoutなどを追加してListViewを追加したFragmentにreplaceしてください。
        //ここではButtonとEditTextで表現します。GridViewに置き換えて考えてください。
        etext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etext);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Fragmentに実装されているonItemAddメソッドを呼び出します。
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onItemAdd(etext.getText().toString);
        }
    }

    private onItemAddListener listener;

    public void setOnItemAddListener(OnItemAddListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public interface onItemAddListener {
        //Fragmentに渡したい値の型を指定します。
        void onAddItemAdd(String label);
    }
}
```

ListViewが追加されているFragmemt
ListFragment.java

```
//importは省略します。
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.OnItemAddListener {
    public ListFragment() {/*empty*/}

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle state) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);

        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setOnItemAddListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemAdd(String label) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + label);
    }
```

Fragmentでの処理はTextViewで表現しましたが、ListFragmentのonItemAddメソッドでの処理内容を変えればListViewへの更新も対応できます。